# Check if a path exist in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, path, verification

I would like to check if files or folder exist in my current project.
I have try using react-native-fs but this not take the files in the project but on the phone.
So for exemple, i would like to get the names of the files like App.js

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why do you need to know if a file exists in the project? What is the issue you're trying to fix?

Comment: I'm creating a language system. so with python and the library googletrans i created all the languages possibles. A json by screen. I get the localisation of peoples with getLocales()[0].languageCode with the library react-native-localize. So i want to check if the folder of this language exist. If it's the case, take the json for the translations if not, take the default language which is english

Comment: You could store an array of which languages/language codes your app directly supports.

Comment: Consider loading all the language files and then check using JavaScript instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a direct answer but in python i made a script that browse all my folders and files and i create a .js file with a huge switch that return the require(my_file) if the desire content is found. False otherwise.
I'm just scare of performances at the end because for now my jsons are empty and for only 5 screens, it's already 525 requiere / files load.